# Why does quicksand get image positions wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, css, quicksand

I've got quicksand set up to sort a list, you can see a demo here (this is a drupal site that I am developing locally, I had to make it a static html page so some things don't look quite right, but you can see the issue):

[website](http://cameronsflash.com/misc/gc2/)

If you make your browser's width 1090px (on the actual site the issue happens across a much broader range of resolutions, but on this demo it only seems to happen at 1090px exactly - at least in chrome) and click "All" you'll notice that the images all wobble a little bit, when really they should not move at all.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add "Position: relative;" to the parent container.  In your case:

```
<div class="mm_quicksand_container">
```

This div should have "position: relative;" on it.  That should get rid of the little wobble/hitch you see when it finishes animating.